# Which novels does The Sky Crawlers movie adapt?

Tags: the-sky-crawlers

According to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sky_Crawlers), *The Sky Crawlers* series consists of 6 books, and one of them is titled *The Sky Crawlers* itself:

> - The Sky Crawlers (スカイ·クロラ)
> - None But Air (ナ·バ·テア)
> - Down to Heaven (ダウン·ツ·ヘヴン)
> - Flutter into Life (フラッタ·リンツ·ライフ)
> - Cradle the Sky (クレィドゥ·ザ·スカイ)
> - Sky Eclipse (スカイ·イクリプス)

There's also [an animated movie with the same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sky_Crawlers_(film)), which is said to adapt the novel, but which novel? Is it only the *The Sky Crawlers* book, or the whole series?